# Why this form is correct in C?

Tags: c, null

I have this piece of code in C:

```
void f(void *x) {
    printf(">>> %p\n", x);
}

int main() {

  f NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

I think is for the definition of NULL, but I'd like an explanation to clarify my doubt.

Comment: what exactly do not you like here?

Comment: iirc NULL is a #define'd to ((void*)0), so when its copied in you have f((void*)0) which works as a parameter for the function

Comment: is the first time that I see this kind of form `f NULL`.

Comment: If you're runing gcc, try gcc -E and see what happens. I think you'll understand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` or `(0)`, then this expands to `f ((void *)0)` or `f (0)`, which are proper function calls. The code errors out for anything non-parenthesized during compilation.

Comment: I downvoted, and removed my downvote after noticing that it was a "monday morning" moment...

Comment: Probably this is consider a stupid question for programmers in C. I'm a beginner of C (but I love it!!). ;)

Answer (score 2):

In C `NULL` is often defined as follows:

```
#if !defined(NULL)
    #define NULL ((void*)0)
#endif
```

If this is the case then `NULL` is just a special pointer, and you example works.

Comment: No, the C standard doesn't define how NULL should be defined.

Comment: Also, `NULL` is not a pointer *to the address 0*. Rather, the *literal value 0*, when encountered in a pointer context, is the null pointer. The *actual* value of the null pointer is implementation-specific and can be anything.

Comment: Fair enough, the standard says that the definition of NULL is implementation specific. However in section 6.3.2.3 part 3, in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf. It says that a `0` cast to (void *) is called a null pointer constant.

Comment: @jbr: Exactly, a *literal* `0` gives a null ptr. But for example, this is not (technically) a null ptr: `int a = 0; void* p = (void*)a;`.